# How to reset files with only whitespace changes in git

Tags: git

In my latest commit I have a lot of files which have only 1-3 empty lines removed. I want to reset these files. Is there a way to do it?

Example:

```
@@ -17,7 +17,6 @@
 package blabla;
 
 import java.util.Date;
-
 import blabla;
 import blabla;
 import blabla;
@@ -17,12 +17,10 @@
 package blabla;
 
 import java.util.Date;
-
 import blabla;
 import blabla;
 import blabla;
 import blabla;
-
 import blabla;
 import blabla;
 import blabla;
```

Basically, the empty lines inbetween the imports are removed and I want to reset these changes. Another option is to ignore them inside gerrit, but as far as understood, there is no way to ignore line changes in vanilla gerrit.

Comment: I guess you were asking for a script implementation? If it's just for a one shot use, maybe simply try `git reset -p` and select chunks manually?

Comment: Use `git diff -w` to prepare your list of which files to fuss with, then use `git reset` (with any desired options) or `git restore` to do said fussing. (Note: if you *are* writing a script, don't use `git diff` in the script. Feel free to use `git diff` on the command line to figure out what the script should do, then pick one of `git diff-index`, `git diff-files`, or the most likely of the three, `git diff-tree` to use *in* the script. These three separate so-called *plumbing* commands ignore user configuration, which might otherwise break the script. But they are more annoying to set up.)

Comment: I created a script, but it wasn't perfect so in the end I created a separate commit with another script, which changes only the imports. I then layered the original commit from stash on top, so that only changes which don't include the imports are inside. Then I cherry-pick the second commit. Very hacky but it worked perfectly.

Comment: @A.Hristov could you please provide your script as answer to the question? Apparently it worked for you and solved your problem. Future visitors with the same question would also like to solve their problem and they can't if you don't share your solution. Stack Overflow is a library with questions _and answers_ about programming-related topics.